# How can I make TextField always placed right above the keyboard?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to make TextField always placed right above the Keyboard when it's clicked. The code does not work as I expect and the TextField is dependent on its position, not the keyboard's(it only works when TextField is below the keyboard)

```
HStack(spacing: 10) {
    TextField()
}
.onAppear {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { (noti) in
    let value = noti.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! CGRect
    self.height = value.height
    self.clickedOut = false
    }
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil, queue: .main) { (noti) in
    self.height = 0
    self.showTextField = false
    }
}

if self.showTextField == true {
    TextField()
    .background(Color("InvertPrimaryFontColor"))
    .offset(y: (-self.height/2) - 12)
    .padding(.leading, -10)
    .animation(.spring())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onEditingChanged` of TextField for solving the issue:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        TextFieldView()
        
    }
    
}


struct TextFieldView: View {
    
    @State private var email: String = String()
    @State private var textFieldIsUnderEdit: Bool = Bool()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            if textFieldIsUnderEdit { Spacer() }
            
            TextField("Enter your email address Here...", text: $email, onEditingChanged: { _ in textFieldIsUnderEdit.toggle() })
                .keyboardType(.emailAddress)
            
            Divider()
            
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
        .animation(nil)
        
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Comment: This only works if the TextField and all of its parent's view don't ignore the bottom safe area otherwise it would be pushed below the Keyboard.

Comment: How did you record that video? :P

Comment: @LeoDabus: It is so easy modify the code for wished result! I was trying gave an idea and a way. Did you control your simulator keyboard options?

Comment: @swiftPunk It is important info for the OP. The keyboard affects the bottom safe area and that's what make it work. I have seen a lot of posts recommending to use the Keyboard notification when they should just respect the safe area.

Comment: @LeoDabus: Yes, that is much better. thanks.